# Unexpected outputs from standalone class with preview and crop options

Tags: standalone, crop, preview

I am designing a logo composed of two letters and am using the `standalone` class. I would expect the newer `crop` option to give me a "tighter" PDF output than the older `preview` option, but the reverse seems to be the case. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0em}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0em}
\begin{document}
\newbox{\Rx}
\newbox{\CRx}
\sbox{\Rx}{%
\fontsize{42pt}{50pt}\selectfont%
{R\hspace{-0.18em}{\raisebox{-0.22em}{\textcolor{gray}{x}}}}%
}
\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{\centering\usebox{\Rx}}
\end{document}
```

The result of the `crop` option is [image]

Whereas, if I replace the class option to be `preview`I get the tighter PDF whose screenshot is [image]

Why is there white space on the left of the crop image and how might it be avoided?

Thanks.

Comment: Both `standalone` options `preview` and `crop` are for cropping. The first one uses the `preview` package internal for that (which allows for paragraph content), the latter own code (which does not allow for paragraph content, and might swallow leading and trailing spaces).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Martin Scharrer. The behaviour I have seen is now comprehensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spurious spaces in your code:

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0em}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0em}
\begin{document}
\newbox{\Rx}% <---
\newbox{\CRx}% <---
\sbox{\Rx}{%
\fontsize{42pt}{50pt}\selectfont%
{R\hspace{-0.18em}{\raisebox{-0.22em}{\textcolor{gray}{x}}}}%
}% <---
\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray}{\centering\usebox{\Rx}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was hitherto unaware that a newline separating two one-line commands, or the newline at the terminus of a multi-line command, could both lead to a spurious space, and thus to unexpected results.

Comment: Well you get a space if you type normal text on two lines, which should it be different if there are commands?

Comment: I was not aware of that either. I tried out what you said and see that the newlines got translated into spaces in LaTeX. I need to pay more attention to terminal whitespace henceforth, including newlines.